# Cannot read from database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my `GET` request

```
var Catalog = mongoose.model('Catalog');
router.get('/catalog', function(req, res, next) {
  Catalog.find(function(err, items){
    if(err){
      return next(err);
    }
    console.log(items);
    res.json(items);
  });
});
```

The model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CatalogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    cost: String,
    description: String
});

mongoose.model('Catalog', CatalogSchema);
```

The `console.log` gives me a `[]` but there is a collection named `Catalog` with the parameters filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing collection, created outside of Mongoose, that you wish to query you need to configure your model to use that collection.

Otherwise, Mongoose will use a utility function to create a collection name by pluralizing and lowercasing the model name (which in your case would become `catalogs`).

To use `Catalog` as a collection, use the [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) option:

```
var CatalogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  cost: String,
  description: String
}, { collection : 'Catalog' });
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I created the collection outside Mongoose and now I can query it!

Answer (score 0):

1. you might check again the collection name in mongodb i.e whether it is 'Catalog' or 'Catalogs'. In my experience I found that if you name the model 'Catalog', then either mongoose creates the collection with a name 'Catalogs' if it is not already there or you have to create the collection first with a name 'Catalogs'.
2. You might check the following line also:

   Catalog.find({}, function(err, items){
   // your code goes here
   }

Hope it helps..